# Reading new process (mongodump.exe) output returns empty string, enabling error hangs the process

Tags: c#, mongodb, process

I am trying to run mongodump and mongorestore from my C# application and capture the output from these applications (dump/restore).

However when i do `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` it always returns an empty string, even though on the calling console app i see the output.

On top of that, when i set `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true`, the process is not running at all and the application is stuck.

Doing the same thing on a different process works (calling the same `CreateMongoProcess` and then trying to read the output like below)

My code:

```
    private Process CreateMongoProcess(string fileToExecute, string arguments)
    {
        var mongoServicePath = Path.Combine(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration["MongoServicePath"], "bin");

        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                WorkingDirectory = mongoServicePath,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = Path.Combine(mongoServicePath, fileToExecute),
                Arguments = arguments,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false
            }
        };

        return process;
    }

    public bool MongoDump(string arguments, string exportPath)
    {
        var finalArgument = $"{GetLocalMongoShellAuthenticationArgument()} {arguments} --out {exportPath}";
        using (var process = CreateMongoProcess(MongoDumpFileName, finalArgument))
        {
            process.Start();
            var x = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // this is empty
            process.WaitForExit();
            //var y = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // when uncommented, its also empty 
            return process.ExitCode == 0;
        } 
    }
```